# Strange(?) ordering in R, min value starts from 10.0

Tags: r, dataframe

I ran into what seems to me very strange behaviour. I am not even sure what details about the code I should provide as this seems so peculiar, but here is the matter. I have a data frame that I am ordering accordingly to a given column value

This is how the data is ordered

```
ordered <- data[order(data[,column]),]
```

The variables column is passed as an argument. This all seems pretty straightforward, but my output below shows as strange ordering.

```
ordered[,column]

 [1] "10.0" "10.0" "10.0" "10.0" "10.1" "10.1" "10.1" "10.1"
 ...
[257] "8.9"  "8.9"  "9.0"  "9.0"  "9.0"  "9.1"  "9.2"  "9.2" 
[265] "9.2"  "9.2"  "9.3"  "9.3"  "9.3"  "9.4"  "9.5"  "9.6" 
 ...
```

As you can see, the data IS ordered, but instead of going from min to max it starts from 10.0, goes until the maximum value, and then starts again from the minimum value.

I have absolutely no clue of what this can be. Any ideas? of what can cause a similar behaviour?

Comment: Those are characters, not numbers. Character sorting is locale-dependent. `?order` tells you to see `?Comparison`, which has more detail and references about character sorting.

Comment: You may want to go back a few steps and make sure your code produces numeric values.  Then the ordering should work.

Comment: Trap for young players here: `"10"` comes before `"9"`, but `9` comes before `10`. Look for the `""` as a tell-tale sign in R that you are dealing with characters not numbers/factors.

Comment: also: search for "lexicographic order"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that's throwing you off is that you're working with characters, not numbers.

To check this for yourself you can use the following:

```
class(ordered[,column])
```